# how to use one feature per sample to predict in sklearn Random Forest?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision, random-forest

I have a data set(of images) with features already populated as `[n_samples,n_feature]` or [10,7]  10 samples with 7 features each.

Now,`.predict()` expects an input of `[n_samples,n_feature]`. I understand the sample size could change but should it not be possible to use just one feature to predict?

Basically, I want only one feature per sample to run through the forest; so input sould be [n_samples,1] during prediction time

Comment: Please make your question a little bit more clear. It's confusing ...

Comment: is it clearer ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Radom Forest` to classify pictures is not that usual and the performance might not be that good.

First, the method `.predict()` does not expect an input of size `[n_samples,n_feature]`. In fact only the number of features `n_features` need to be the same, that's not the case for `n_samples`. While your training set has some `16*16=256` samples, your test set can only consist of one sample.

If you still want to use a `RF` classifier using only one feature, you might compute a **principal component analysis** (which might not return a feature amongst your features) **or** select your best feature by using some classical **skleanr** methods such as : [SelectKBest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest) that allows you to select the K best features (in your case `K=1`).

---

### UPDATE :

I've just looked a little bit deeper in sklearn's API documentation and found this : [see here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.transform)

You can give to your `.transform()` method a parameter called `threshold` that will select features according to your given threshold.

**ATTENTION** : DEPRECATED: Support to use estimators as feature selectors will be removed in version 0.19. Use SelectFromModel instead.

Comment: So its not possible to make the random forest accept only one feature during test ?

Comment: I was expecting one feature to be run down the tree and only training require multiple features per sample. Is there any way around ?

Comment: Oh no that you cannot. If you want to keep a given features, train your data on it and then using on your test set.

Comment: Can you suggest how I can go around this ? Maybe another library ?

Comment: You just cannot train on multiple features and test on different set of features.  It goes against the principles of machine learning. Your classifier cannot guess how to split according to new given features.

Comment: If you want to use only one feature for your test set, then retrain another classifier on your train set only on that feature and then predict the test samples

Comment: To be very precise, Im attempting a pixel based classification. For a single pixel I will be extracting `n` features  in a random fashion. this is for training the tree. But during run-time I want to extract just one. and pass it down the tree. Am I approaching it the wrong way ?